ACF WordPress Map User To Custom Post Type
I have created a series of text fields, a User field and a repeater field (with sub fields) which displays when I create a new post under the Custom Post type "deliveries" from the backend. I am wanting to attach the post type, to a specific user (Which I select from the User field dropdown)
From there, I am wanting to display the sub field repeater values (e.g. Repeater field data) from the post which a selected user is assigned to, on to the frontend of my website for the current logged in user. If there isn't any posts assigned to a partciular, then a message would display e.g. "No deliveres found for your account".
add_shortcode('display_delivery_info', 'render_delivery_info');
function render_delivery_info() {

    $customer_delivery = wp_get_current_user();
    $customer_id_delivery = get_current_user_id();
    

if( have_rows('parcel_update_manager', 'user_', $customer_id_delivery ) ): ?>

    <ul>

    <?php while( have_rows('new_parcel_update', 'user_', $customer_id_delivery) ): the_row(); ?>

        <li><?php the_sub_field('delivery_status'); ?></li>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

    </ul>

<?php endif; 

}

At the moment, the above code isn't returning any data from the fields I have created and I'm unsure to whether I've missed a vital step beforehand - Would I need to add an action to assign a user to the custom post type I have created, in order to display the relational data on to the frontend of my website (For my user to view when they are signed in?)
(I'm a newbie to ACF, so I'm currently just following the guidance on the Repeater Fields documentation, with trying to get this to work)
Thanks!
